# Laravel migration - Update id field from integer auto increment to string

Tags: laravel, migration

I tried to change `id` field from Integer auto increment to string but after I run migrate, the structure of MYSQL's not change.

This is my code:

```
Schema::table('table', function ($table) {
    $table->dropPrimary();
    $table->string('id', 50)->change()->primary();
});
```

Please help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```
Schema::table('table', function ($table) {
    $table->dropPrimary('id');
    $table->string('id', 50)->change()->primary();
});
```

Also you should check if `doctrine/dbal` is installed successfully

Comment: If this solve your problem then please accept the answer so that others may find it useful